# How to Re-apply for a UK after Refusal

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, nigerian-citizens

I once applied for UK visa two years and was refused on the basis of not meeting certain conditions which are as follows:

1. I applied with an invitation from someone (packaged as such by an agent) who I said was my sister. But when the UK consulate tried to reach her on several occasions based on the contact number we provided, she was unreachable. By that they said they could not establish the relationship between us neither could the really verify the invitation.
2. I provided a personal statement of account which had some money it and at the same time provided the certificate of a fixed deposit I had with the bank at the time. The consulate said they were not sure that such money would be available for my traveling and as such could not grant the visa.

Note: these were the key reasons stated in the refusal letter, the others I can't remember but I want to believe those are trivia.

Question: I am planning to reapply again in the next couple of months and this time I want to go with my newly wedded wife for our honeymoon without invitation from anyone and without the assistance of any traveling agent. My question is this, the part where we be required to fill if we have any relation in the UK, what should I write there? My previous application stated I had someone in the UK (lie), can I state now that I don't have any relation in the UK (true)? If yes, won't this contradict what they have in their data base?

Also, currently I'm a director in a company and I have the company certificate. Is that enough for me or do I need to go with any other document?

Please advise.....thanks

Comment: Have you considered going somewhere else for your honeymoon?

Comment: @DJClayworth Somewhere like where?? Do you any nice and interesting place in mind?

Comment: The problem is, a) Nigerian, b) using an agency, c) apparent funds parking, d) fake sponsor, e) past lying, f) getting turned away, g) "director of a company with *certificate*" what the heck is that? Also h) you seem weirdly obsessed *with the UK specifically*.  Nigerians have a rep for lying to get in, then working illegally or hanging on the dole... and you *did try* that.  How can you prove, **beyond a shadow of a doubt**, that you aren't now?  That's what they're looking for.

Comment: @Harper As much as I appreciate your comment and contribution, your points could have been better made without being harshly critical of me. You aren't a consular and I don't think there is anything wrong with being a liar in the past and now you want to amend your ways. I would like to state here that you're not a said either about having to tell lies at some point in your life.
Moreso, I don't think my intentions is any body's business what I ask is not for you to mentor me but rather a guide. Lastly, if you care to know, I'm not in Nigeria and UK can't offer me anything at this time . thks

Comment: @laurilking sorry, space was too limited to express concepts gracefully.  Not attacking you, just making clear what you're up against so you can focus your efforts correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You should never lie on a visa application!

That you did so previously is not a good reason to do so now. If you once again falsely claim to have a relation to someone in the UK, your applicaction might be refused just for that lie, you don't want that. I would imagine a history of lying also increases your chance of being banned from making further applications, you don't want that either.

I believe you also have to state in the application that you've applied before, also make sure to be honest there. There is probably space to admit your previous lie, but else I suppose the officials processing your application will understand what's going on.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63836/discussion-on-answer-by-henrik-how-to-re-apply-for-a-uk-after-refusal).